# When I put object into the body I get different field names

Tags: java, json, jackson, httpclient, rest-assured

The object "info" when go into body method it should have another fields name. e.g. brandName->BrandName, id-> Id etc.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Laptop")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Laptop")
public class ComputerInfo {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @SerializedName("BrandName")
    private String brandName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @SerializedName("LaptopName")
    private String laptopName;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @SerializedName("Features")
    private Feature features;

    @XmlElement(name = "BrandName")
    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "LaptopName")
    public String getLaptopName() {
        return laptopName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Features")
    public Feature getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }


    public void setBrandName(String brandName) {
        this.brandName = brandName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLaptopName(String laptopName) {
        this.laptopName = laptopName;
    }

    public void setFeatures(Feature features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ComputerInfo{" +
                "brandName='" + brandName + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", laptopName='" + laptopName + '\'' +
                ", features=" + features +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Feature {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    @SerializedName("Feature")
    private ArrayList<String> feature;


    public ArrayList<String> getFeature() {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature(ArrayList<String> feature) {
        this.feature = feature;
    }

}
```

My Test

```
  @Test
  public void testPostWithObjectMapping() throws URISyntaxException {

    URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/laptop-bag/webapi/api/add");
    String id = new Random().nextInt(500) + "";

    ComputerInfo info = new ComputerInfo();
    info.setBrandName("Microsoft");
    info.setId(id);
    info.setLaptopName("Surface");

    Feature feature = new Feature();

    feature.setFeature(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("8GB RAM", "1 TB Hard Drive")));
    info.setFeatures(feature);

    Response response = given().accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .log()
            .body()
            .with()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(info)
            .post(uri);

    response
            .thenReturn()
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            .body("Laptop.Id", equalTo( info.getId( )));
}
```

Result:

> ComputerInfo{brandName='Microsoft', id='421', laptopName='Surface',
>   features=http_client.models.Feature@cb51256}

But it should be

```
Laptop{BrandName='Microsoft', Id='421', LaptopName='Surface', Features=""}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SerializedName` is Gson's annotation, not Jackson's

You should use `@JsonProperty("BrandName")` instead of `@SerializedName("BrandName")`

Comment: A have added @JsonProperty("BrandName"), but it does not help me

Comment: The same result